# How to avoid collapsing a wrapped union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

It appears to me that Typescript is collapsing a wrapped union type (undesired) when it happens to know the initial value. I'm not sure that this is a bug, but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid it.

An example:

```
type Prime = 3|5|7;
type OrDonuts<T> = T | 'donuts';

function compare<T>(a: T, b: OrDonuts<T>) {
    return a == b;
}

let value: Prime;
compare(value, 3);
// OK!

value = 5;
compare(value, 3);
// TS2345: Argument of type '5' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OrDonuts<3>'
```

In order to get around this error, I have to explicitly uncollapse by saying things like `value = 5 as Prime;`.

Is this a bug, expected behavior, am I just doing it wrong?

(node: 10.15, typescript: 3.5.1)

Comment: One slight issue making your example more awkward to understand is that the first call has an error as well (`value` is uninitialized). You might use `declare` to get around that without assigning it a value in the code (and thus triggering the narrowing you're having an issue with), [like this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLbQLxQMwB8CsWDsA3AFCiRQDycAIgPYB2ArsAM4A8AKgHxTodRYoAcgAmDZiyEliAM0b0AxsAQMoC2kjABDOBE5cAFFoBcUDgBooAI1NU6TVvoCUUAN7EonqLuCM49KC1edCsSAF9iYhEIBQAbHWhYiGAoADctWMYIU3hkCBJ1TQSDdMyISwwnEgB6asoAaQBCSNKs3igcAo1tXRKMrIqqoA).

Comment: Since the compiler is telling you that the call to `compare` is unnecessary (may as well just use `false`), why is it a problem that it narrows `value` like that when presented with a literal value? This is one of the benefits of static analysis.

Comment: [A relevant issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31734) although I'm looking for a canonical reference about union-typed variables being narrowed on assignment.  Narrowing is very often desired, but in your case it leads to unexpected behavior.  You'll have to do `let value: Prime = 5 as Prime` or `let value = 5 as Prime` if you want to disable that narrowing.

Comment: Okay, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513) is the canonical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TypeScript type checker performs [control flow type analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#control-flow-based-type-analysis), meaning that it makes an effort to determine what happens to the values inside variables at runtime and will narrow the types of these variables to match.  One of the specific ways this happens is if you have a variable or property of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), and the compiler sees you assign a more specifically-typed value to it, it will narrow the type of the variable to that more specific type, at least until you assign some different value to the variable.

This is very often desirable, since it supports use cases like this:

```
let x: number | string = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "hello" : "goodbye"; // x is string now
if (x.length < 6) { // no error here
  x = 0; // the widest x can be is string | number, so this assignment is fine
}
```

Note that even though you have *annotated* that `x` is a `number | string`, the compiler understands that it will definitely be a `string` after the initial assignment.  So it does not complain when you check `x.length` (as it would if `x` could possibly be a `number`).  This is such a useful behavior that to disable it would lead to lots of real-world TypeScript code breakage.

Unfortunately, it's also responsible for the behavior you're seeing here.  After assigning `5` to `value`, the compiler sees `value` as containing a variable of the narrowed type `5`.  Not `Prime`.  You can always *widen* `value` to `Prime`, but the compiler will not do that automatically.  It thinks it is helping you by warning you that you are calling `compare(5 as 5, 3)` which is forbidden.

In this case, the only way to override this behavior is with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), as you've seen.  You can do this assertion either on the initial assignment, or inside the call to `compare()`:

```
let value2: Prime = 5 as Prime
compare(value2, 3); // okay

let value3: Prime = 5;
compare(value3 as Prime, 3); // okay
```

Or, you could manually specify the generic type `T` in your call to `compare()`, which also works:

```
let value4: Prime = 5;
compare<Prime>(value4, 3); // okay
```

Any of those options are available to you.

The most canonical source of documentation I can find for this is [Microsoft/TypeScript#8513](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513), and specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8513#issuecomment-217678711).

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLbQLxQMxQD5QKw5QDsA3AFCiRQDycAIgPYB2ArsAM4A8AKgHxTpuhAEQATZm3bDyZAGYsmAY2AJmURQyRgAhnAg9eACm0AuKNwA0UAEZnajVhwMBKKAG8yUKHuAs4TKG0BdGtyAF8yMgAbCGAoADdtKJYIM3hkNHxyDS1dCENE5IgrDGcSKAB6CqgIODgGOEiYuMKUgCY0xBQBfED2WC6IMhydPQKk9pKyyuqGAGttECbYhImIDE6MnrxszVH81vW+gYyp8qqoecXllrWAFk3u9B3hvbzOdJQjQ7uzmcuFiAgA)

Comment: Thanks for the addl links, I agree that the behavior is far more helpful than hurtful.  Causes some unexpected side effects with, say, `jasmine` typings on e.g. `Expected<Enum>`, but the workaround is pretty simply now that I know it's expected.

Comment: Is it really the type of `5`? Because if you try to assign `1` to it, it will complain that it is not of type `Prime`.

Comment: It's control flow analysis. "If the compiler sees you assign a more specifically-typed value to [a union-typed variable], it will narrow the type of the variable to that more specific type, at least until you assign some different value to the variable."  I'm not sure what you're asking... why would you be allowed to assign a value of type `1` to a variable of type `Prime`?  The compiler doesn't completely forget the annotated type of the variable; it just treats the value as the narrowed type.

Answer (score 1):

It is the intended behavior of [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types). By declaring

```
type Prime = 3|5|7; // it is either 3 OR 5 OR 7 but never all of them at the the same time
```

you tell the ts-compiler that `Prime` is one of the values. Now you assign `5` to the typed field `value`.

```
value = 5; // type Prime is now 5
compare(value, 3); // <T> is inferred by the ts-compiler as 5
```

In order to fix this you have to use `value:Prime` or type assert as you did.

---

Without type inference you would be able to pass `value` e.g.

```
value = 5;
compare<2>(value, 3); // Argument of type '5' is not assignable to parameter of type '2'.
```

or if you would satisfy the `compare` function parameter in a more generic way like

```
let test = 5;
compare(test, 3); // <T> is now number which 5 and 3 are.
```

Comment: *"Now you assign 5 to the un-typed field value which is perfectly fine."* `value` isn't untyped. It's `let value: Prime;`. It's just above the OK example.

Comment: But `value` is declared as a `Prime`; it is not untyped. ([Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLbQLxQMxQD5QKw5QDsA3AFCiRQDycAIgPYB2ArsAM4A8AKgHxTpuhAEQATZm3bDyZAGYsmAY2AJmURQyRgAhnAg9eACm0AuKNwA0UAEZnajVhwMBKKAG8yUKHuAs4TKG0BdGtyAF8yMgAbCGAoADdtKJYIM3hkNHxyDS1dCENE5IgrDGcSKAB6CqgIODgGOEigA)) This is happening because union typed variables are narrowed upon assignment, which is *usually* desirable.

Comment: @jcalz Updated it. Pinging

Comment: This answer is still not addressing the issue in the question... see the link in my above comment; an explicitly annotated variable is being treated as a narrower type.  This is intended behavior but has nothing to do with type inference (also note, the word is "inference", not "interference", although I can see why a frustrated developer might use the latter term )

Comment: @jcalz ^^ some comments deserve multiple upvotes, sadly SO won't let me. :-)